# How to check if a method calls another method from the same class?

Tags: ruby, mocking, minitest

I am trying to set up a unit test, using Minitest, for a class. In this class, some of the methods call other methods.

This is a very simplified concept of what I am trying to do.

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class Book
    def caller
        self.called
    end

    def called
        nil
    end
end

class BookTest < Minitest::Test
    def test_checkCaller
        fake = Minitest::Mock.new
        fake.expect(:caller, nil)
        fake.caller
        assert(fake.verify,msg=nil)
    end
end
```

This returns:

```
Run options: --seed 24362

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.002716s, 368.1771 runs/s, 368.1771 assertions/s.

1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

I'm not even sure if this is doing what I want. What I want is to confirm that `called` is being invoked by `caller`.

I also, later, want to test that when I send a certain message into `caller`, then a certain code is run by `called`, such as adding that message to a queue.

[Before anyone marks this as a duplicate, make sure that the supposed post is actually the same as what I am asking, and preferably has a legitimate answer to my question. I have looked at multiple similar posts and each are slightly different.]

Thanks!

Comment: Note: This sort of goes against the spirit of unit testing. You should be testing that you get the desired *results*, not that it used the correct *implementation*. If you need to test some behaviour that's internal-only that's usually a sign you're digging too deep into the guts of your code and aren't testing it at the right level.

Comment: @tadman Are you saying that I should only be doing: input -> class -> output? Therefore only caring about the output itself?

Comment: I'm saying you should be testing outcomes, not implementations. You should be inspecting the before and after state of objects to verify they're behaving correctly. You should not be testing that they called particular methods to achieve that outcome. Leave the implementation details out of your testing so that you're free to re-implement those without breaking tests. This is one of the principles of *programming by contract*. Your tests establish a contract saying "So long as when I do X I get Y (or does NOT do something) then the implementation is valid."

Comment: @tadman That makes a lot of sense. I was under the impression that I needed to test each method in itself, like unit testing the methods, but that is wrong. Thank you!

Comment: You'll want to unit-test any public methods your object exposes, don't get me wrong, but anything that's labelled `private` or `protected` is off-limits by design. That's a way of saying "I reserve the right to change the way these methods work without warning." Public methods should have a well-defined set of expectations for both input, output, and acceptable use cases (e.g. pre-conditions for calling them, data duck-typing expectations, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. This has given me a far better understanding of unit testing and saved me much time. Not even considering the tens of classes and hundreds of methods I would have improperly tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use a gem called `spy`. This way you can essentially *spy* on a method and see if it was called. https://github.com/ryanong/spy

Comment: Though I no longer intend to do as I asked, I like the options given by this gem. I'll test it and if it works as I wanted, then I'll mark it. Thanks!